# Monomorphism restriction in pattern bindings

Tags: haskell

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}
module Try where

f :: IO (a -> IO String)
f = return $ const getLine

main :: IO ()
main = do
  g <- f
    :: IO (a -> IO String)
  g "String" >>= print
  g 5 >>= print
```

Even with the `NoMonomorphismRestriction` flag and explicit type signature, this module fails to compile with `Couldn't match expected type ‘[Char]’ with actual type ‘Int’`, despite `g` being fully polymorphic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not what the monomorphism restriction means.  The monomorphism restriction says that if a definition has no type signature and has a left-hand side with no parameters, it will be specialized to a monomorphic type (or rather just monomorphic enough to get rid of any class constraints). You have given type signatures so it doesn't apply.

The problem here is that you have given the wrong type to `f`.

```
f :: IO (a -> IO String)
```

actually means

```
f :: forall a. IO (a -> IO String)
```

That is, *first* pick a type `a`, then you can bind to get a monomorphic function of type `a -> IO String` for that `a`.  There is no trouble with this program, for example:

```
main = do
    g <- f
    g "String" >>= print
    g' <- f
    g' 5 >>= print
```

But your usage example requires this type:

```
f :: IO (forall a. a -> IO String)
```

That is, you want to bind first and pick the type later, i.e. use the function at multiple types.  This is called an "impredicative type" and unfortunately GHC has not supported them for quite a while, as far as I know.

The way to solve this problem is to make a `newtype` wrapper that explicitly quantifies the inner polymorphic type:

```
newtype R = R { getR :: forall a. a -> IO String }

f :: IO R
f = return $ R (const getLine)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    g <- f
    getR g "String" >>= print
    getR g 5 >>= print
```

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't sure if it was the monomorphism restriction or not, and the closest thing I could find was `NoMonoPatBinds` but that didn't help either.

Comment: It is worth noting that the only inhabitants of the type `forall a. a -> IO String` are things of the form `\_ -> x`, where `x :: IO String`. Unless there is additional information that has been omitted for simplicity, the `R` should just be `newtype R = R (IO String)`, in which case it can be dispensed with altogether.